# Event Listener is not removing

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to remove the Event Listener that i created but unable to do that, don't know where I am going wrong.
Any help is highly appreciated.

```
const [windowEvent, setWindowEvent] = useState(false);

function handleClick(){
  alert("Mouse Pressed!!");
}

useEffect(function(){

  if(!windowEvent){
    window.removeEventListener("dblclick",handleClick);
  }
  else{
    window.addEventListener("dblclick",handleClick);
  }
},[windowEvent]);
return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => setWindowEvent(prevState => !prevState)}>Toggle Window Event</button>
    {windowEvent && <WindowEvent />}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Effect subscribes to something, you need a cleanup function that should unsubscribe.

```
  useEffect(
    function () {
      if (windowEvent) {
        window.addEventListener("dblclick", handleClick);
      } 

      return () => window.removeEventListener("dblclick", handleClick);
    },
    [windowEvent]
  );
```

[React beta](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#subscribing-to-events) docs explains clearly how to subscribe to events

**Edit**
Removed useless else statement

Comment: Why is that if statement is unable to remove it.

Comment: @SrijanSaini Because react will call the cleanup function each time before the effect runs again. So it mounts without the event, each time the state changes it will trigger a render and the effect will run again and it will set the `EventListener`. Next time the state updates, the clean up function will remove the`EventListener` before the effect runs again.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(function(){
    window.addEventListener("dblclick",handleClick);
    return  () => window.removeEventListener("dblclick",handleClick);
},[windowEvent]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "dblclick" event does not exist on the window object, as can be seen in [this list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#events). You can only do it on elements.